# An elegant approach to comparing many int variables to a value - C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, integer, compare

Of the two current answers, I have chosen the one using the range based for loop as it better addressed my first requirement which is to avoid being lengthy. The answer with the variadic template is interesting (and I will try it out!) but lengthier than I would like (since I want everything done inside the same function I mentioned with the variables).

If anyone else comes up with another method, I will still pay attention (even in the far future!) and am always happy to select a possibly better solution ;)

---

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional, C++, MFC

---

I have a strange question which might have no solution

I have a function that comes across several `int` variables, say I have six in total: `int1`, `int2`, `...`, `int6`.

I want to compare each of these values to `-1`. If any of them `== -1`, then the `void` function `return`s, exiting early.

I know the first idea you may come up with is a lengthy `if` statement, possibly with several branches like:

`if ( (int1 == -1) || (int2 == -1) || ... || (int6 == -1) ) { return;}`

or

```
if (int1 == -1) { return;}
else if (int2 == -1) { return;}
...
else if (int6 == -1) { return;}
```

Another idea is to push all these `int`s to a `std::vector<int>` then iterate through them, comparing each element to `-1` with an `if` clause and `return`ing if there is a match. **This is the plan I will fall back to *if* there is no other solution.**

Is there a way to check these values with a more elegant approach that is:

1. not lengthy
2. does not use a container such as `std::vector`
3. does not use much more memory than either of the two ideas above

Again, **I completely understand if there is no method that fits my specifications**, and in that case I will go with the `std::vector` approach. And I do know that at some point I have to bite the bullet and get to comparing the `int`s but I am interested if there is some other method!

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance ! :D

Comment: Add one to each integer, and then multiply them together. If the result is zero then one of the original integers must have been -1. This is not a serious suggestion, apart from being obscure, unless your integers are small there is a risk of integer overflow.

Comment: Any time I see something on the order of "int1" through "int6", the first thought that comes to mind: this should be an array.

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind would be bitwise operators. -1 XOR -1 = 0 for instance. You could start there.

Comment: @john haha ! I read the first sentence and thought 'I like where this is going' then I gave it a second more and laughed :) and yes the overflow is worth noting, but in my case my values will be in the range of -1 to 31 except for one which will be around 2000-2040 (it will be storing years)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a range based for loop as for example

```
for ( const auto &item : { v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 } )
{
    if ( item == -1 ) return;
}
```

or in C++ 20

```
for ( int value = -1; const auto &item : { v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 } )
{
    if ( item == value ) return;
}
```

If you do not want to create copies of the variables in the `std::initializer_list` then use `std::reference_wrapper`. As for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>


int main()
{
    int v1 = -1, v2 = -2, v3 = -3, v4 = -4, v5 = -5, v6 = -6;

    for ( auto item : { std::ref( v1 ), std::ref( v2), std::ref( v3 ),
                        std::ref( v4 ), std::ref( v5 ), std::ref( v6 ) } )
    {
        if ( item == -1 )
        {
            std::cout << "There is element with the value -1\n";
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... would it invike a copy...

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie And what is the problem?

Comment: what would invoke the copy constructor here ?

Comment: @HusamChekfa Use std::reference_wrapper.

Comment: I forgot if initializer list would be another storage.. that was against OP wishes :P

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie See my appended answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a variadic template with a fold expression.

```
template<typename ...T>
bool any_equal_to_minus_1(T... t) {
    return (... || (t == -1));
}

...
    if (any_equal_to_minus_1(int1, int2, etc)) return;
```

You could then wrap your function on call side, saving you the typing of variables:

```
void your_function_real_part(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3);
    
template<typename ...T>
void your_function(T... t) {
    if (any_equal_to_minus_1(t...)) return;
    your_function_real_part(t...);
}

int main() {
    your_function(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Heh, posted almost at same time, but you got example